# Testing truth/falseness in bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sh

For some reason, I can't figure out how to test truth in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
FORCE_DELETE=""
BE_VERBOSE=""

OPTIND=1
while getopts ":fv" FLAG "$@" ; do

    if [[ "$FLAG" == "f" ]] ; then
        FORCE_DELETE="true"
    fi
    if [[ "$VALUE" == "v" ]] ; then
        BE_VERBOSE="true"
    fi

    if [[ "$FLAG" == "?" ]] ; then
        echo "Usage: $0 [-fv] file ..."
        exit 1
    fi
done

shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`

if [[ "$FORCE_DELETE" == "true" && "BE_VERBOSE" == "true" ]] ; then
  echo "FORCE_DELETE AND BE_VERBOSE $@" 
elif [[ "$FORCE_DELETE" == "true" ]] ; then
  echo "FORCE_DELETE $@" 
elif [[ "$BE_VERBOSE" == "true" ]] ; then
  echo "BE_VERBOSE $@" 
else
  echo "$@"
fi

exit 0
```

Transcript:

```
$ test a b  
a b  
$ test -f a b  
FORCE_DELETE a b  
$ test -v a b  
a b  
$ test -fv a b  
FORCE_DELETE a b
```

Why does my bash script respond to the -f flag but not the -v flag?

Comment: You're missing the `$` before `BE_VERBOSE` in the first `if`.

Comment: is it a typo ? `[[ "$VALUE" == "v" ]]`, shouldn't this be `[[ "$FLAG" == "v" ]]`

Comment: @Barmar, that should probably be an answer.

Comment: @CarlNorum Actually, iamauser's comment is more pertinent.

Comment: All the problems are just trivial typos, this question should just be closed.

Comment: Ahh, this is embarrassing...will fix typos and edit question after testing.

Comment: You don't need to quote variables inside `[[...]]`, even if they have embedded whitespace (you do with single`[`).  Also `true` and `false` can be used as values without quotes (they are bulletin to bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a typo :

```
[[ "$VALUE" == "v" ]],
```

this should be

```
[[ "$FLAG" == "v" ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You specifically ask about testing true/false.  These are built in to the language rather than using strings, and you don't need the `[[` test.  Here is how I would write this:

```
#!/bin/bash
force_delete=false         # Don't use UPPERCASE
be_verbose=false           # they could collide with reserved variables

# OPTIND does not need to be initialised
while getopts :fv flag
do
    # appears one of your if statements is incorrect
    # a case is often used with getopts
    case $flag in
    f) force_delete=true
       ;;
    v) be_verbose=true
       ;;
    \?) echo "Usage: $0 [-fv] file ..."
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))  # don't create a child process for simple arithmetic   

if $force_delete && $be_verbose
then
    echo "force_delete AND be_verbose $@"
elif $force_delete
then
    echo "force_delete $@"
elif $be_verbose
then
    echo "be_verbose $@"
else
    echo "$@"
fi

# Bash exits 0 by default
```

Comment: In the while loop, what is the purpose of ;; ?

Comment: @mchenja: The `;;` terminate each code block in the `case` statement.